# Service deployed on Tomcat crashing under heavy load

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, centos

I'm having trouble with a web service deployed on Tomcat. During peak traffic times the server is becoming non response and forces me to restart the entire server in order to get it working again.

First of all, I'm pretty new to all this. I built the server myself using various guides and blogs. Everything has been working great, but due to the larger load of traffic, I'm now getting out of my league a little. So, I need clear instructions on what to do or to be pointed towards exactly what I need to read up on.

I'm currently monitoring the service using JavaMelody, so I can see the spikes occurring, but I am unaware how to get more detailed information than this as to possible causes/solutions.

The server itself is quad core with 16gb ram, so the issue doesn't lie there, more likely in the fact I need to properly configure Tomcat to be able to use this (or setup a cluster...?)

JavaMelody shows the service crashing when the cpu usage only gets to about 20%, and about 300 hits a minute. Is there any max connection limits of memory settings that I should be configuring?

I also only have a single instance of the service deployed. I understand I can simply rename the war file and Tomcat deploys a second instance. Will doing this help?

Each request also opens (and immediately closes) a connection to mySQL to retrieve data, I probably need to be sure it's not getting throttled there too.

Sorry this is so long winded and has multiple questions. I can give more information as needed, I am just not certain what needs to be given at this time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server has 16Gs of ram but how much memory do you have dedicated to tomcat, -Xms and -Xmx?

Comment: My assumption would be the default. 

I just searched the commands you provided, it appears this will change the app heap size? Can you give me a more specific example? What should/can I set it too?

Comment: Something big! I don't know what else is on your sever. You have 16Gs -Xms14G -Xmx14G. It's something you definitely need to play with.

Comment: It's dedicated. So, my question now is how do I apply this, am I appeding it as params to the end of this line?
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh

Comment: look for JAVA_OPTS or CATALINA_OPTS in that file. If you're around the SF area you can contact me for more help.

Comment: Ok, I believe I have achieved this by: export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms14G -Xmx14G" but not really sure how to check if this was successful

Comment: Memory chart hasn't changed, but it's also not the one that appears to be hitting it's limit. cpu seems to max out at 25% and active threads at 200 - can these be increased too?

Comment: Yes, you can increase the thread count. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/executor.html
How about some up points :-)

Comment: I've added the maxThreads value to the server.xml file assuming that's where the throttling was occurring... The tomcat manager/status is showing the increase, but the JavaMelody chart still shows 200 (I'm hoping it's dynamic based on the max reached) Guess I'll find out tomorrow when everyone attacks it again.